# Missing M2_REPO classpath variable when I open Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath

I'm working with Eclipse IDE and I've already configured maven settings.

I did **Windows -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations** and I added my own maven installation. Then I did **Windows -> Preferences -> Maven -> User Settings** and I checked that it pointed to the correct settings.xml and my Local Repository. Everything is ok, and I clicked on Update Settings and Reindex just in case.

The first time I did this, in **Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variable** there was a variable called **M2_REPO** and it pointed to the correct repository. But the next day I opened again Eclipse, the **M2_REPO** variable was gone.

Am I missing any further configuration? Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I'm using Windows 7.

UPDATE 2:

I don't know why I have to do this `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in cmd before running eclipse to have all the projects correctly. This could be a solution.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: You created Environment variable for that ?

Comment: @Ved Do you mean MAVEN_HOME? or another variable? MAVEN_HOME is created.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-configure-m2_repo-variable-in-eclipse-ide/) leads you through defining the `M2_HOME` variable with various methods; personally I prefer the automatic definition via the command line call

```
mvn -Declipse.workspace="your Eclipse Workspace" eclipse:configure-workspace
```

For example you may use something like this:

```
mvn -Declipse.workspace="C:\workspace" eclipse:configure-workspace
```

if your workspace is under `C:\workspace`.